# JMeter SocketException on .png,.jpg etc files

Tags: jmeter

I am running a Jmeter script in version 2.8. After running script in result
tree i am getting below mentioned error. But this error is not coming to
any specific request. I am getting this error for any random request. If i
ran test 1st time i am getting error for one png request. In next run same
png request passed successfully and error is seen for some different
request.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) at
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218) at
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258) at
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) at
sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:116) at
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116) at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2676)
at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:99)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256) at
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) at
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1620)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:236)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:512)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1054)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1043)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:271)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reflects server side issues as you are getting connection reset error.
If you are doing real load test, do it in NON GUI mode, GUI mode is for scripting.

Comment: I need to check if any of the pages is taking too long to respond or load. Will NON-GUI mode cater that? What if some png or js file is heavy and it is causing time delays?

Comment: NON GUI will not cater that as it's a server side issue. Yes it could be a js or png is causing time delays. It also could be related to GUI mode usage particularly if you use the View Tree Results, see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html